# How to make uploadify upload as drag and droppable for uploading the images?

Tags: c#, asp.net, uploadify

Do anyone have any example for uploading multiple image through DRAG and DROP. For now I am using uploadify upload for uploading multiple image and binding it into datalist. It is working very well.

but now i want to convert this into drag and drop, so user need not to click on btn and select files, he/she just select the images and drag and drop it and it gets upload and bind it in datalist.

Comment: thank you for your ans but i am so sorry your ans is not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need a DragDrop event set, the put the following code:

```
void Form_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Extract the data from the DataObject-Container into a string list
    string[] FileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);

    // Do something with the data...

    // For example add all files into a simple label control:
    foreach (string File in FileList)
        this.label.Text += File + "\n";
}
```

Comment: I want to make my image upload something like http://krystalware.com/slickupload/demos example